# windows service c# - error 1053

Tags: c#, windows, windows-service

Crie uma aplicação Windows service c#, utilizo um setup project para fazer a instalação do serviço no windows, quando tento iniciar o serviço no windows ocorre o seguinte erro:

error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Já criei ServicesPipeTimeout com um tempo maior no regedit, porém não resolveu.

Meu método onStart contém varias threads que vão executando durante todo o processo de execução do sistema.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Thread tEnviarEmailPendente = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.enviarEmailPendente));
        Thread tBaixarResumoNfe = new Thread(new ThreadStart(baixarResumoNfe));
        Thread tBaixarXmlNfe = new Thread(new ThreadStart(baixarXmlNfe));
        Thread tConsultaSituacaoNfe = new Thread(new ThreadStart(consultaSituacaoNfe));
        Thread tManifestarNfe = new Thread(new ThreadStart(manifestarNFe));
        //Thread tBaixarResumoNfc = new Thread(new ThreadStart(baixarResumoNfc));

        try
        {
            tEnviarEmailPendente.IsBackground = true;
            tBaixarResumoNfe.IsBackground = true;
            tBaixarXmlNfe.IsBackground = true;
            tConsultaSituacaoNfe.IsBackground = true;
            tManifestarNfe.IsBackground = true;
            //tBaixarResumoNfc.IsBackground = true;

            tEnviarEmailPendente.Start();
            tBaixarResumoNfe.Start();
            tBaixarXmlNfe.Start();
            tConsultaSituacaoNfe.Start();
            tManifestarNfe.Start();
            //tBaixarResumoNfc.Start();

            tEnviarEmailPendente.Join();
            tBaixarResumoNfe.Join();
            tBaixarXmlNfe.Join();
            tConsultaSituacaoNfe.Join();
            tManifestarNfe.Join();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            erro_log el = new erro_log();
            el.erro_codigo = ex.HResult;
            el.erro_descricao = ex.StackTrace;
            el.servico = "Obter configuracao";
            el.data = DateTime.Now;
            _control.salvarErro(el);
        }
        finally
        {
            wait = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você utilizou os arquivos da pasta `debug` para realizar a instalação, tente instalar utilizando os arquivos da pasta `release`.

(No meu caso utilizei o InstallUtil.exe)

[Post relacionado.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158371/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-tim)